# Javascript innerHTML basic issue

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to insert string into HTML using Javascript innerHTML property.
But it's not working. I tried with `showtime()` function at the first, and I added `window.onload` at the front because it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
  window.onload = function Hello() {
  var timeArea = document.getElementById("time");
  var text = "Hello";
  timeArea.value = text;
};
Hello();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="time">
   What time is it?
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `timeArea` refers to `DIV` which doesn't have `value` property. either use `innerHTML`/`textContent `. May be you need `timeArea.textContent += text`

Comment: Where is `innerHTML`?

Comment: Just google it....
here is the first result at: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Apart from the value/textContent confusion, notice, that the `Hello` call in the script triggers an error, and possible code after that line will never be executed. The name of a named function expression is accessible only within the function itself (and via a debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.value` use the `.innerHTML` you are trying to insert the text in the html.

`.value` is used for input type not for html tags and not to insert the text inside the html tags.

```js
window.onload = function Hello() {
  var timeArea = document.getElementById("time");
  var text = "Hello";
  timeArea.innerHTML = text;
};
```

```html
<div id="time">
   What time is it?
</div>
```

Also remove the `hello()` function called after the `window.onload`. `window.onload` will automatically execute the hello function.

Comment: Please provide an explanation why this answers the question instead of just posting code.

Comment: @PatrickHund I was editing the post dude. And till then you gave the downvote. I know there are require the explanation also.

Comment: @CodeLღver — If you post a bad answer and then edit it to make it better, you should expect people to vote it down while it is bad! **Finish** writing answers **before** you click *Post Your Answer*.

Comment: @Quentin ok, I agree. I remark this for next time. I found the issue and have the solution so I became more excited.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Div elements dont have a value property.
if you want to insert some text you need to change your code to this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function Hello() {
        var timeArea = document.getElementById("test");
        var text = "Hello";
        document.getElementById("test");
        timeArea.textContent = text;
        };
</script>
    <div id="time">
       <p id="test">

       </p>
    </div>
```

I created a P element so you can modify its text at will, and print it in a p. You can use any other element as H1, H2, and so on.

textContent select the text from that element and making it equal to the variable text print its value.

I know this has been answered but this is just another way of doing it.